# Copy build outputs from multiple projects to same folder

Tags: workflow-foundation, tfsbuild, build-server

I have a Visual Studio 2013 Solution with custom project types provided by a plugin. These projects do not support specifying the build outputs folder or post build events. I need to copy the build outputs from the outputs location of each project to a single `bin` folder such that they can be uploaded to a drop location in TFS. How would I write a batch script or similar to copy the outputs from

```
\SolutionDir\Project1\Debug\Win32\*
\SolutionDir\Project2\Debug\Win32\*
...
```

to

```
\SolutionDir\bin\Debug\Win32\*
```

Bearing in mind that some projects depend on others and therefore the same `.dll` may be present in multiple locations. It doesn't matter which I keep. I tried something like

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir *.dll *.exe /b /s /a-d') do copy "%a" "bin" /y
```

But that does not preserve the `\Debug\Win32` folder structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work it out with the help of a batch script which I called `CopyBins.bat`. It is not particularly elegant, but here it is;

```
dir /b /s /ad | find "\%1\" > folders.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('cat folders.txt') do xcopy /s /y "%%a" %1\
del folders.txt
```

Then I can execute it by calling

```
CopyBins Debug
```

Bear in mind that I can't just execute

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /b /s /ad | find "\Debug\"') do xcopy /s /y "%a" Debug\
```

Because I get the error

```
| was unexpected at this time.
```

If anybody has a better solution I would like to hear it...